# XCode 5.1 Unit Test Coverage Analysis Fails On Files Using Blocks

Tags: xcode, gcov, lcov, xcode5.1, test-coverage

Today I was tasked with adding unit test coverage analysis to our code base. Today is also the day iOS 7.1 is released along with XCode 5.1. From the release notes:

> The gcov tool for code coverage testing has been reimplemented. The new version uses the llvm-cov tool from the LLVM project. It is functionally equivalent to the old version for all significant features. The location of gcov within Xcode has also moved, use xcrun to invoke it. If you find problems, please file bug reports. For this release, you can still use the old version of gcov from GCC, which is available as gcov-4.2. 11919694 updated

I realized this only after following several [instructional](http://www.silverbaytech.com/2013/03/04/ios-unit-testing-part-4-code-coverage/) [blog](http://qualitycoding.org/xcode-code-coverage/) [posts](https://www.cocoanetics.com/2013/10/xcode-coverage/), getting my environment set up properly - generating .gcda/.gcno files in the simulator's build folders upon testing - and having the report generating tools [here](https://github.com/jonreid/XcodeCoverage) try to parse them into a report. (that is a ./getcov script which gathers your environment variables to pass to lcov-1.10 scripts to generate the report)

The first hurdle was that the new bundled `gcov` program doesn't support the `-v` argument to get the version, which is the first step of `lcov`'s initialization. Seemed like a non-starter already, but reading the release notes above I modified the `lcov` script to use the  old `gcov-4.2` version and got that solved.

However, `lcov` errored out very early in processing my coverage data files. This generated a report with maybe the first 10 or so files alphabetically in my project. Not particularly useful. The error output was minimal and unhelpful as well:

> geninfo: ERROR: GCOV failed for (build_artifacts)/(class_that_errored).gcda!

I modified the `lcov` script to print the error it was getting (which only yielded `11` unfortunately, couldn't find any reference in the gcov(-io).c code) and to continue operation instead of quitting, so I was left with a lot more files in the report, but still probably 85% of my source files had errored out as above.

The only pattern I could discern between the files that successfully wound up in the report and the ones that threw an error was that any file that used an in-line block declaration failed. None of the files that passed used blocks in any fashion, and all the files I've checked that failed contain blocks. Strange.

Then I figured out I could open the individual .gcda files in [CoverStory](https://code.google.com/p/coverstory/), including the ones that had errored in the `lcov` script. In the message window beneath the coverage report, all the files that had errored had the warning messages:

> (class_that_errored).gcno:no lines for '__copy_helper_block_'
>
> (class_that_errored).gcno:no lines for '__destroy_helper_block_'

My best hypothesis at this point is that the new XCode 5.1 is generating .gcda files that the old `gcov-4.2` program isn't equipped to deal with regarding block declarations.

But I've exhausted everything I can think to try, so I'm here to ask if anybody has a piece of knowledge that I've missed, or has any ideas to further the debugging effort. Or if anyone is successfully measuring test coverage since today's XCode 5.1 update with the new `gcov`, I'd love to hear about any changes you had to make as well.

Comment: Also need an answer to this issue - I'm having exactly the same issue with Xcode 5.1. Our code coverage dropped from 52% coverage of 16,800 lines to about 57% coverage of 12,000 lines. We're also seeing issues with the two block lines mentioned.

Comment: I'm using gcovr (available here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gcovr) to interpret the coverage results, and that's getting even more inaccurate answers than CoverStory gets. The GCDA files it fails to process generate an error of "MySourceFile.m: No such file or directory". Strangely, invoking gcov directly on the GCDA file in question seems to create the appropriate file. If anyone can shed any light on this, please create an answer below!

Comment: Additionally, function measurement—as opposed to source/line measurement—seems to be absent. Before Xcode 5.1, lcov was able to measure both.

Comment: @Endersstocker Not sure why this has changed, but if you explicitly instruct lcov to derive the data using the --derive-func-data argument, the original behavior is restored.  I just added the argument to the gather_coverage() function in Jon Reid's getcov shell script.

Comment: @jstevenco I've tried adding that to the gather_coverage() function - this doesn't seem to fix the issue unfortunately. Classes that use blocks still seem to not be getting coverage.

Comment: @David-Doyle Actually, my comment was aimed at @ Endersstocker's observation about function measurement not working.  Not sure what is going on with the block issue, but in my limited evaluation, I am getting coverage of classes/methods that include blocks (e.g., I am using AFNetworking 2.0 with success/failure completion blocks).  Any noticeable pattern on problem block contents?

Comment: I've a suspicion (not proven yet but I will look into) that its on classes that create blocks for internal use, rather than classes that supply a block to another class. This isn't proven yet though.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't been able to reproduce the issue in a test class yet. However: the root cause is definitely in llvm-cov. For the gcda files which don't get any coverage generated at all, running llvm-cov on them directly generates not one .gcov file, but two - the first is genuine (reports: "File '/Users/me/Dev/MyProject/MyFramework/Controller/DGDViewController.m'
Lines executed:57.58% of 858") with the right coverage data, but the second seems to be blank (reports: "File 'MyFramework/Controller/DGDViewController.m'
Lines executed:nan% of 0"). Still not able to reproduce this though!

Comment: @LeffelMania were you able to solve this ? I have the same problem

Comment: I've switched my coverage analysis to use `gcovr`; I gave up on this `lcov` setup.

Comment: Did that solve the problem? I'm still using gcovr and get the same issue ...

Comment: Yup, it's working for me. My whole setup is setting the required build settings for generating coverage symbols (`Generate Test Coverage Files` and `Instrument Program Flow`), running my tests, and generating my report by running `gcovr --html -html-details -f ".*MyClasses.*" -e ".*MyExclusions.*" -o "coverage-report/index.html"` in the build objects directory. (With directory maintenance added, of course)

Comment: @LeffelMania What version of gcovr are you using? I'm using 3.1 (which appears to be the latest but I may not be looking in the right place ...) and this seems to have a similar issue (Got error: Unexpected number of edges (in -[MyController layoutViews]).
Invalid .gcda File!) ...?

Comment: Weird. I'm on 3.1 as well and have been having good luck with it. Not sure I can help. :-/

Comment: I was investigating the issue that all files with blocks in them are missing in the coverage report generated by gcovr, when stumbling upon this question. Desperately I tried building with Xcode 6 beta 3 ... and the issue seems to be gone!
Upgrading to the Xcode beta is not an option for me, but at least I know that it will be fixed in a future Xcode version!

Answer (score 13):

The problem is in the LCOV 1.10 **geninfo** script. It tests for the current version of gcov. It does this by parsing the version string. Since gcov now points to llvm-cov, the version string is parsed incorrectly.

The solution is to modify **geninfo**’s get_gcov_version() subroutine. In line **1868**, change `-v` to `--version`. Then replace line **1874** with:

```
if ($version_string =~ m/LLVM/)
{
    info("Found llvm-cov\n");
    $result = 0x40201;
}
elsif ($version_string =~ /(\d+)\.(\d+)(\.(\d+))?/)
```

The modified subroutine should look like this:

```
sub get_gcov_version()
{
    local *HANDLE;
    my $version_string;
    my $result;

    open(GCOV_PIPE, "-|", "$gcov_tool --version")
        or die("ERROR: cannot retrieve gcov version!\n");
    $version_string = <GCOV_PIPE>;
    close(GCOV_PIPE);

    $result = 0;
    if ($version_string =~ m/LLVM/)
    {
        info("Found llvm-cov\n");
        $result = 0x40201;
    }
    elsif ($version_string =~ /(\d+)\.(\d+)(\.(\d+))?/)
    {
        if (defined($4))
        {
            info("Found gcov version: $1.$2.$4\n");
            $result = $1 << 16 | $2 << 8 | $4;
        }
        else
        {
            info("Found gcov version: $1.$2\n");
            $result = $1 << 16 | $2 << 8;
        }
    }
    return ($result, $version_string);
}
```

<sup>***NOTE:*** Make sure `--gcov-tool` is **not** set to `gcov-4.2`.</sup>

Comment: Have tried switching to using the XcodeCoverage tool as above, and it seems even more broken than gcovr is with Xcode 5.1. Its not even able to produce any report at all with my current setup ...

Comment: @DavidDoyle: Does getcov return errors or do you just receive a blank report?

Comment: @DavidDoyle: Can you let me know what they are?

Comment: Too many to post in one go, so I'll break them up into three parts:

Comment: gcov: Unknown command line argument '-v'.  Try: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/gcov -help'
gcov: Did you mean '-a'?
gcov: Not enough positional command line arguments specified!
Must specify at least 1 positional arguments: See: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/gcov -help

Comment: geninfo: Use of uninitialized value $version_string in pattern match (m//) at ./XcodeCoverage/lcov-1.10/bin/geninfo line 1874.
geninfo: Use of uninitialized value $version_string in pattern match (m//) at ./XcodeCoverage/lcov-1.10/bin/geninfo line 1879.
geninfo: Use of uninitialized value $gcov_version_string in pattern match (m//) at ./XcodeCoverage/lcov-1.10/bin/geninfo line 3627.
geninfo: Use of uninitialized value $gcov_version_string in pattern match (m//) at ./XcodeCoverage/lcov-1.10/bin/geninfo line 3627.

Comment: Scanning /Users/david/Dev/MyGit/Build/MyProj/Obj.root/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/i386 for .da files ...
geninfo: ERROR: no .da files found in /Users/david/Dev/MyGit/Build/MyProj/Obj.root/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/i386!

Comment: @DavidDoyle: Did you change `-v` to `--version` on line **1868** in the **geninfo** get_gcov_version() subroutine? That should address the '-v' error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49765/discussion-between-david-doyle-and-endersstocker)

Comment: To summarise: This does seem to fix the issue with lcov, but the original issue seen (anything with a block in it doesn't appear in the coverage report) is still present ...

Comment: In this case and all those solutions offered so far, function measurement (as opposed to source/line measurement) is absent. Before Xcode 5.1, lcov was able to measure both.

Comment: using the XcodeCoverage tool found at `https://github.com/jonreid/XcodeCoverage.git` will also solve the `gcov: Unknown command line argument '-v'.` error, however its seems like classes with blocks will throw an error and stop generating the coverage file, leading to very misleading results. We have a class that uses blocks that begins with the letter `A` so we went from a very decent amount of coverage to 1%.

Comment: `NOTE: Make sure --gcov-tool is not set to gcov-4.2.1` Is there a specific version that is working for you? Or should version any above this work?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than modifying `geninfo` I created an `llvm-cov-wrapper` script and used lcov's `--gcov-tool` command line option:

```
#!/bin/bash
# llvm-cov wrapper to make it behave more like gcov

if [ "$1" = "-v" ]; then
    echo "llvm-cov-wrapper 4.2.1"
    exit 0
else
    /usr/bin/gcov $*
fi
```

Comment: it says Must specify at least 1 positional arguments:

Answer (score 2):

Actually I noticed that lcov is invoking gcov with -b option and gcov-4.2 will crash on this option (raise segmentation fault). If I remove the -b option from getinfo, then even though it still shows some error info, the gcov file can still be generated.

That is probably why coverstory can still give coverage output. So I guess the workaround is to remove -b option from lcov. And also as you suggested, ignore the error in getinfo

Answer (score 0):

For anyone new to this thread, note that lcov-1.11 is out. This eliminates the issue with `gcov -v` compatibility.  However, I am using XCode 6.1 and still getting errors on some files.

`geninfo: WARNING: /Users/XXX/MyFile.gcno: found unrecognized record format - skipping`

Note that you can add `--ignore-errors graph` to skip over these errors, but the problem isn't really solved.