# Invalid cobertura report

Tags: xcode, jenkins, cobertura, gcov

I have to set up code coverage reports in Jenkins. I use gcovr to generate the reports. gcovr generates the report file.xml and this file is full. And I have got the following trouble:

```
                       ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                       File                Lines    Exec  Cover   Missing
                       ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                       Mr.m                125       0     0%   26,37-46,50,55-78,84-108,113-130,142-160
                      ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                      TOTAL                                        125       0     0%
                      ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And my code coverage report in Jenkins is not valid. Cobertura says that there is no code coverage at all. But I know that I have coverage.

I'm using:

gcovr 3.2-prerelease
Xcode version 5.0.2

Comment: I have not used gcovr before. But I have seen this page sometime back. Hope it helps. Good luck! http://www.kinoshita.eti.br/2012/10/16/adding-coverage-reports-in-jenkins-to-googletest-with-gcovr.html

Comment: Ongoing investigation into this issue here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343725/xcode-5-1-unit-test-coverage-analysis-fails-on-files-using-blocks