# gcov file checksums do not match when processing gcda

Tags: code-coverage, gcov

After using XCode 5.1, I got an error like this:

```
gcov: Unknown command line argument '-v'.  Try: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/gcov -help'
```

Then I find an answer from this page: [XCode 5.1 Unit Test Coverage Analysis Fails On Files Using Blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343725/xcode-5-1-unit-test-coverage-analysis-fails-on-files-using-blocks)

However, I got another error like this:

```
Processing *****.gcda
File checksums do not match: 1280071245 != 5 in ().
Invalid .gcno File!
geninfo: ERROR: GCOV failed for ****.gcda!
```

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343725/xcode-5-1-unit-test-coverage-analysis-fails-on-files-using-blocks

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't help.

Comment: I'm suddenly getting this too. Not sure what changed.

Answer (score 0):

For me the cause was that the *.gcno files were stale and did not match the *.gcda files. In fact most of them had gone missing.

Fixed this by doing the following:

- Ensured that both: 'instrument program flow' and 'generated test coverage' were set in both the App's target and the test target.

I then added the following to the AppDelegate.

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    extern void __gcov_flush(void);
    __gcov_flush(); //ensure all coverage data is flushed before shutdown
}
```

. . this is for application hosted iOS tests. Depending on your requirements you could make this a little less 'invasive' (eg, mix in the coverage flushing so that its only in your test target), but this should be a good starting point to get it working first.

Comment: Also note that with the current version of Xcode, there's a new version of gcov. If you're using the lcov tool to generate HTML reports, you need to hack the geninfo script as it doesn't know about llvm-gcov yet. Details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22404544/404201