# LCov - Found unrecognized record format errors

Tags: xcode, code-coverage, gcov, lcov

I've looking to get an HTML code coverage report working with an XCode 6.1 based project.  My solution 'partially works', but I'm getting a lot of skipped files when running lcov:

```
geninfo: file found unrecognized record format - skipping
```

---

Some more detail on my setup:

1. Created an XCode 'Coverage' configuration via these instructions (Steps 1+2):
   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1514/_index.html
2. Build and run my standalone testrunner using this configuration via `xcodebuild`.

This successfully appears to generate `GCNO` files and `GCDA` files for each of my source files. So far so good.

3. Run `lcov` (v1.11) to generate an HTML report.  The command I'm using looks like the following:

   ```
   lcov --capture --derive-func-data --directory ./build/Coverage/MyCppRunner.build --output-file lcov-testrun.info --ignore-errors graph
   ```

This also succeeds, due to the `ignore-errors` argument. However, I'm getting a lot of skipped gcno files with the following error:

```
geninfo: WARNING: /Users/myname/build/Coverage/MyCppRunner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MyFile.gcno: found unrecognized record format - skipping
```

When I generate my HTML report via `genhtml`, these files don't show any coverage.

Is there any way around this issue? A different set of `clang` flags perhaps, or an alternative to `lcov`? I briefly tried `gcovr`, but I couldn't get it working.

Comment: I've come across this error too. See this related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343725/xcode-5-1-unit-test-coverage-analysis-fails-on-files-using-blocks/28533416#28533416  though it didn't fix it for me